# How prevent NaN and Infinity result after submit calculation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I have simply JavaScript code. It's CBD dosage calculator. (even I don't know how I got it :D ) but, after submit button I get NaN or Infinite when some input is empty. How I can get alert or do nothing when inputs are empty or one of them.

```js
const dropperSize = 0.05; // ml
const bottleSize = 10; // ml
const cbdConcentration = document.getElementById("cbd-concentration");
const calculateButton1 = document.getElementById("calculate-button-1");
const result1 = document.getElementById("result-1");

const weight = document.getElementById("weight");
const strength = document.getElementById("strength");
const calculateButton2 = document.getElementById("calculate-button-2");
const result2 = document.getElementById("result-2");

// Calculator 1: CBD per drop
calculateButton1.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let cbdConcentrationValue = cbdConcentration.value;
  let cbdPerMl = cbdConcentrationValue / bottleSize;
  let cbdPerDrop = cbdPerMl * dropperSize;
  result1.innerHTML = `One drop contains ${cbdPerDrop} mg of CBD.`;

});

calculateButton2.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let weightValue = weight.value;
  let cbdInDrop = cbdin.value
  let strengthValue = strength.value;
  let cbdDose;
  if (strengthValue === "low") {
    cbdDose = 2;
  } else if (strengthValue === "medium") {
    cbdDose = 7;
  } else if (strengthValue === "high") {
    cbdDose = 13;
  }
  let cbdPerDay = weightValue / 10 * cbdDose;
  let numDrops = cbdPerDay / cbdInDrop;
  let roundedDrops = Math.round(numDrops);
  if (isNaN(roundedDrops)) roundedDrops = 0;
  let mgCbdPerDay = roundedDrops * cbdInDrop;
  if (isNaN(mgCbdPerDay)) mgCbdPerDay = 0;
  result2.innerHTML = `Môžete užívať ${roundedDrops} kvapiek denne. Čo predstavuje ${mgCbdPerDay} mg CBD`;
});
```

```html
<div class="cbd-calculator">
  <p>
    Vypočítajte si koľko mg CBD je v jednej kvapke a podľa závažnosti Vášho problému zistite, koľko kvapiek CBD denne uživať.
  </p>
  <span>Celková koncentrácia CBD ( koľko mg CBD je vo fľaštičke )</span>
  <input required id="cbd-concentration" type="number" placeholder="500" />
  <button id="calculate-button-1">Koľko CBD obsahuje jedna kvapka</button>
  <p id="result-1"></p>
  <span>Váha (kg):</span>
  <input required id="weight" type="number" />
  <span>Koľko mg CBD je v jednej kvapke</span>
  <input required id="cbdin" type="number" />
  <span>Požadovaná sila</span>
  <select required id="strength">
    <option value="low">Nízka</option>
    <option value="medium">Stredná</option>
    <option value="high">Vysoká</option>
  </select>
  <button id="calculate-button-2">Vypočítať</button>
  <p id="result-2"></p>
</div>
```

I have tried to put `isNaN()` but now is showing `Infinity` when one of the inputs is empty. How can I get a notification or not show anything when I confirm the button?

Comment: Please add your HTML also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just added some validation checking with condition like `weightValue == ''`

```js
const dropperSize = 0.05; // ml
const bottleSize = 10; // ml
const cbdConcentration = document.getElementById("cbd-concentration");
const calculateButton1 = document.getElementById("calculate-button-1");
const result1 = document.getElementById("result-1");

const weight = document.getElementById("weight");
const strength = document.getElementById("strength");
const calculateButton2 = document.getElementById("calculate-button-2");
const result2 = document.getElementById("result-2");

// Calculator 1: CBD per drop
calculateButton1.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let cbdConcentrationValue = cbdConcentration.value;

  if (cbdConcentrationValue == '') {
    alert('fill the fields') // write your message
  } else {
    let cbdPerMl = cbdConcentrationValue / bottleSize;
    let cbdPerDrop = cbdPerMl * dropperSize;
    result1.innerHTML = `One drop contains ${cbdPerDrop} mg of CBD.`;
  }

});

calculateButton2.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let weightValue = weight.value;
  let cbdInDrop = cbdin.value
  let strengthValue = strength.value;
  let cbdDose;

  if (strengthValue === "low") {
    cbdDose = 2;
  } else if (strengthValue === "medium") {
    cbdDose = 7;
  } else if (strengthValue === "high") {
    cbdDose = 13;
  }
  if (weightValue == '' || cbdInDrop == '') {
    alert('fill the fields') // write your message
  } else {
    let cbdPerDay = weightValue / 10 * cbdDose;
    let numDrops = cbdPerDay / cbdInDrop;
    let roundedDrops = Math.round(numDrops);
    if (isNaN(roundedDrops)) roundedDrops = 0;
    let mgCbdPerDay = roundedDrops * cbdInDrop;
    if (isNaN(mgCbdPerDay)) mgCbdPerDay = 0;
    result2.innerHTML = `Môžete užívať ${roundedDrops} kvapiek denne. Čo predstavuje ${mgCbdPerDay} mg CBD`;
  }

});
```

```html
<div class="cbd-calculator">
  <p>
    Vypočítajte si koľko mg CBD je v jednej kvapke a podľa závažnosti Vášho problému zistite, koľko kvapiek CBD denne uživať.
  </p>
  <span>Celková koncentrácia CBD ( koľko mg CBD je vo fľaštičke )</span>
  <input required id="cbd-concentration" type="number" placeholder="500" /><br>
  <button id="calculate-button-1">Koľko CBD obsahuje jedna kvapka</button>
  <p id="result-1"></p>
  <span>Váha (kg):</span>
  <input required id="weight" type="number" /><br><br>
  <span>Koľko mg CBD je v jednej kvapke</span>
  <input required id="cbdin" type="number" /><br><br>
  <span>Požadovaná sila</span>
  <select required id="strength">
    <option value="low">Nízka</option>
    <option value="medium">Stredná</option>
    <option value="high">Vysoká</option>
  </select><br><br>
  <button id="calculate-button-2">Vypočítať</button>
  <p id="result-2"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Iam still lerning so this helped me a lot.

Comment: Hello, please how is possible to do something like this: After submit button add class to element which show this result ( div or bootstrap info massage ). Thank you.

Comment: @Ľubo do you want the result to look like bootstrap alerts

Answer (score 0):

First make it a function. Put the values ​​you want to check in if. if it doesn't compare its terms, send alert and return

Answer (score 0):

In `calculateButton2.addEventListener` you can check if weight.value, cbdin.value and strength.value are defined. If they are not, you can use [alert("Your message")](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) function to notify user.